# Motion tracking points are not accurate enough

Tags: tracking

I want to get a more accurate track, but some of the makers seem to have a mind of their own and are bouncing all over. I am not sure if this problem is caused either by some of my settings, my footage, or just Blender not being able to do a good job. (Possible?)

My footage was shot using an iPhone 4, focal length of 35 I think (It changes whenever I solve to 41.14).

If my footage being too blurry is the problem (I think that it's not too blurry), I tried changing the Tracking Present to Blurry Footage and that didn't change anything that I noticed. Same with the rest of the presets.

What would fix the markers from jumping around?

[GIF of Footage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi4qP.jpg)

Comment: Well, your "marks" aren't that great. If you later want to render something on top of your desk, how about you just paint 2 or 3 little pieces of paper in a nice flashy color and put the on your desk? Blender should then be able to do better tracking. Also, the tracking doesn't look that bad. For jumping markers, you can "retarget" them manually.

Comment: What isn't that great about the markers? I thought it looks best with a black and white look, that the keyboard has.